# vb winform custom event handler

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to add custom event handler on user control.

if I create user control on the same solution and on the same project, I can add custom event handler on the main form.

AddHandler usercontrol1.button.click, addressof button_clickHandler

when I type in usercontrol1. I can select button from the pop-up code completion

but if I create another project for user control on the same solution, say user control called uc
so after I place it on the main form with name uc1

AddHandler uc1.button.click...

when I type in uc1. I can't see button on the pop-up code completion and when I compile it if I type in
AddHandler uc1.button.click, addressof button_clickHandler2

**I get compile error uc1.button is not accessible in this context because it is friend.**

does user control custom event only work if the user control created on the same project?

I am thinking just to separate common user control and other common library, in one project, so it can consume by other project, instead of creating the same user control on each project.

I appreciated if you could give some pointer on how to create custom event handler or I just have create user control on the same project to get it to work.

Thank you.

Comment: This has got nothing to do with user controls or event handlers and is simply about access level. You obviously don't know what `Friend` means so you should find out what it means and what the alternatives are.

Comment: If in doubt or you're experiencing compiler errors, start with `Public` then back off access as necessary/preferred. (IMHO always restrict access to the minimum you can get away with, eg `Private`, `Protected`, `Protected Friend`, `Friend`, `Public` - have I missed any?) Some only apply in certain situations such as `Class Property`. Refer to doco for defaults, such as `Class` where access level isn't declared (you should *always* declare access, again IMHO). (Obviously, there's a lot more to this than I've written here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the simple solution is to just declare the child control(s) `Public` instead of the default `Friend`, good practice would be to not expose child controls of a user control anyway, no matter where it's declared. Child controls should be made `Private` and you should provide pass-throughs for any properties, methods or events you wish to access from the outside. For instance, declare your own `ButtonClick` event in the user control, handle the `Click` event of the `Button` internally and then raise your own event, e.g.

```vb
Public Event ButtonClick As EventHandler

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    OnButtonClick(EventArgs.Empty)
End Sub

Protected Overridable Sub OnButtonClick(e As EventArgs)
    RaiseEvent ButtonClick(Me, e)
End Sub
```

Your form will then handle events of the user control and not its child controls. See [here](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/11/defining-and-raising-custom-events.html) for more information about declaring and raising your own events.

BTW, a reason not to make child controls `Public` is that then any code that has access to the user control has access to EVERY aspect of the child controls, including being able to replace them with new controls. By making them `Private` and providing pass-throughs, you expose only the specific aspects of the child controls that should be accessible from the outside. It also means that your user control behaves more as an integrated unit, rather than a collection of parts. On the matter of events specifically, it also means that the user control is the `sender` in each event handler, rather than the individual child control.